# Vectorizing a very simple pandas lambda function in apply

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, apply

pandas `apply/map` is my nemesis and even on small datasets can be agonizingly slow. Below is a very simple example where there is nearly a 3 order of magnitude difference in speed. Below I create a `Series` with 1 million values and simply want to map values greater than .5 to 'Yes' and those less than .5 to 'No'. How do I vectorize this or speed it up significantly?

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.rand(1000000))

# vectorized and fast
%%timeit
ser > .5
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 477 µs per loop

```
%%timeit
ser.map(lambda x: 'Yes' if x > .5 else 'No')
```

1 loop, best of 3: 255 ms per loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`np.where(cond, A, B)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the vectorized equivalent of `A if cond else B`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(np.random.rand(1000000))
mask = ser > 0.5
result = pd.Series(np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No'))
expected = ser.map(lambda x: 'Yes' if x > .5 else 'No')
assert result.equals(expected)
```

---

```
In [77]: %timeit mask = ser > 0.5
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [76]: %timeit np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No')
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop

In [73]: %timeit pd.Series(np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No'))
10 loops, best of 3: 86.5 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit ser.map(lambda x: 'Yes' if x > .5 else 'No')
1 loop, best of 3: 223 ms per loop
```

---

Since this Series only has two values, you might consider using a [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) instead:

```
In [94]: cat = pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=mask.astype(int), categories=['Yes', 'No']); cat
Out[94]: 
[No, Yes, No, Yes, Yes, ..., Yes, No, Yes, Yes, No]
Length: 1000000
Categories (2, object): [Yes, No]

In [95]: %timeit pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=mask.astype(int), categories=['Yes', 'No']); cat
100 loops, best of 3: 6.26 ms per loop
```

Not only is this faster, it is more memory efficient since it avoids creating the array of strings. The category codes are an array of ints which map to categories:

```
In [96]: cat.codes
Out[96]: array([1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=int8)

In [97]: cat.categories
Out[99]: Index(['Yes', 'No'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks very good. About a 40x speedup but still about an order of magnitude slower than a straight up vectorized boolean comparison.